# Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my simple jQuery code in which is used to hide/show a dynamic element

```
$('.network').click(function() {
    if($("a[data-network='all']").hasClass('active')) {
        if($(this).data("network") !== "all") {
            var network = $(this).data('network');
            switch(network) {
                case "fb":
                    $(".facebook").hide("slide", { direction: "up"  }, 2000);
                break;
                case "tw":

                break;
                case "all":

                break;
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

When running the `click()` function it's pushing `Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function` to the console.log

The error is coming from this line

```
$(".facebook").hide("slide", { direction: "up"  }, 2000);
```

Comment: which line is causing the error

Comment: edited question to provide that, thanks

Comment: What is the `direction` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) along with jQuery to support this format of hide function.

The default [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function provided by jQuery takes only two parameters - duration and complete callback, but [the one](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) provided by jQuery-UI support more options

So either you can include jQuery-UI to the project or change the code as

```
$(".facebook").slideUp(2000);
```